# How to handle UnauthorizedAccessException in asynchronous code?

Tags: c#

Catching an `UnauthorizedAccessException` works fine, but it doesn't when I make the `File.WriteAllBytes` -> `await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllBytes(Path + vid.FullName, vid.GetBytes()));`
When I do this the exception doesn't get caught. What's the best way to catch this exception, so that the MessageBox shows? Thanks.

(NOTE: This code is clearly a YouTube converter, but it is for **my own personal use**)

```
 public async Task ConvertVideoAndDownloadToFolder(string link, string MP3Name = null)
        {
            try
            {
                var youtube = YouTube.Default;
                var vid = await Task.Run(() => youtube.GetVideo(link));
                await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllBytes(Path + vid.FullName, vid.GetBytes()));
                var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = Path + vid.FullName };
                MediaFile outputFile;
                //Creates mp4 and mp3
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(MP3Name)) { outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = $"{Path + vid.FullName}.mp3" }; }
                //only creates MP4
                else { outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = $"{MP3Name}.mp3" }; }

                using (var engine = new Engine())
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => engine.GetMetadata(inputFile));

                    await Task.Run(() => engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Can't write on '{Path}' as it is protected.\rPlease choose another folder. ", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
                else if(ex is ArgumentException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"'{link}' is not a valid YouTube link, \rMake sure the video still works, or check the link for typos. ", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Await `Task.Run` in an attempt to make something asynchronous. I/O operations usually have real asynchronous methods. For example, open a file stream and `WriteAsync` to it directly.

Comment: @poke How would this look like in code? I'm new to asynchronous programming so I don't really get it. (Sorry for my ignorance)

Comment: There's no point in any of those `Task.Run` usages, it's just adding a load of synchronisation overhead for no reason.

Comment: @Oliver, Task.Run is used as a hack to free the thread, so if this is WinForms/WPF application (Which it probably is judging by the `MessageBox.Show`).  The UI thread won't be blocked.  However, they probably should add `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: @johnny5 But they are awaiting each `Task`?  Surely that's enough to still block the UI thread?!  The OP could simply use `async` all the way given what appears to be going on in the tasks.

Comment: @Oliver No, the UI thread will not be blocked.  The UI Thread won't be able to continue logically because it's awaiting, but that doesn't mean it's blocked.   The function called is async, the ui thread will still be free to do certain operations e.g still able to resize etc.

Comment: @johnny5 That still seems odd to me given it **would** be blocked without the `await Task.Run(...`, I guess the difference hinges on `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which **isn't** in the OP's original code. Even with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, in my opinion there's still no point in those `Task.Run usages` where `async`/`await` can be used all the way down (like writing bytes to a file).

Comment: The await with the task run will queue the task up with the threadpool.  The threadpool will pick it up. The existing thread will be free to do other things like resize etc.  Await does not block. It's uses hardware interrupts to continue. So if you're calling await on a thread it's free to do whatever in the meantime.

Comment: @johnny5 Got it, the confusion stems from my lack of WPF/WinForms experience and how `async void` events are managed by the framework. However I still think `async`/`await` all-the-way where possible would be preferred, rather than wrapping what can be otherwise awaited with `Task.Run`.  It would certainly make exception handling easier - the crux of the question.

Comment: @Oliver, I'm not talking about `async void` i'm talking about `async/await` when using await your thread is only blocked by CPU intensive work.  When wrapping the func in Task.Run it offloads the work to the thread pool.  The pattern they're using is just a hack to avoid spinning up a background process to offload the work to.

Comment: @Mayfair , it will be great if you can mark the below post as resolved, if you think it as answered your query ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asynchronous programming it is very easy for exceptions to be swallowed as they typically run on another thread. This needs to be carefully managed

*AggregateException stores all the exceptions that happen in different threads and therefore you do not lose any exception*

```
catch (AggregateException aex)
{
     foreach(var ex in aex.InnerExceptions) //This will consolidate t
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=netframework-4.8)