# Progressbar not showing up when indeterminate (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf

yesterday I posted this: [How to handle UnauthorizedAccessException in asynchronous code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848856/)
Someone said it was best to leave the Task.Run out of there because it was unnecessary.

So I did but now another problem has come up. This is the code without the async but I only removed the async arguments so if you want to copy code go to my previous post. https://i.stack.imgur.com/f82gE.jpg

My current problem lies within this code:

```
    progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    youtubeConverter.ConvertVideoAndDownloadToFolder(txtInputLink.Text);
    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Whenever this method gets called, the progressbar doesn't show. Even if you remove the last line, it only gets visible after the method is done, even though I ask the progressbar to show up right before. The progressbar works without the method so I'm clueless to why this happens. (I'm talking about `ConvertVideoAndDownloadToFolder()` method)

In other words, I want my progressbar to show up when the method is loading so that the user knows the application is busy, and not stuck. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks alot, have a good day.

Comment: without async you can't show as it won't wait for the Progress bar ...

Comment: "Someone" tell you to remove combinations of `await` + `Task.Run()` inside the method to make it synchronous, but the method itself should be called with `await` + `Task.Run()`, otherwise you are blocking UI thread and it's unable to draw progress. Btw, you could have just posted question title into google to get [answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+progress+bar+not+showing+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Sinatr Yes, you're right. I didn't realise that. I'll try to do what you said, thanks. I'll also edit my post about what 'someone' said.

Comment: Rather than posting an image of your code post a link to a pastebin or something similar. If you start the method in async you'll need to change UI elements in UI thread. If you were to use Bindings and MVVM, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @XAMIMAX, I'm aware that I posted an image, hence why I said if you want to copy the code, go to my previous post. I was on a short time frame at the time of posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI thread cannot display the `ProgressBar` and execute the `ConvertVideoAndDownloadToFolder` method at the same time.

You should execute `ConvertVideoAndDownloadToFolder` on a background thread. The easiest way to do this is to create a `Task`. Once the task has completed, you set the `Visibility` back to `Collapsed` on the UI thread:

```
progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
string s = txtInputLink.Text;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => youtubeConverter.ConvertVideoAndDownloadToFolder(s))
    .ContinueWith(_ => progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed,
        CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

If you are in the context of an `async` method, you can simplify this by awaiting the task:

```
progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
string s = txtInputLink.Text;
await Task.Run(() => youtubeConverter.ConvertVideoAndDownloadToFolder(s));
progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: What can I do if I have to UI operations? For example, I am updating a Datagrid and want to show a Progressbar until the UI operation is finished? As soon as the grid is changed the progress bar is stuck until the grid operation is finished.

Comment: @H.Füreder: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.

Comment: I am out of questions